# Say sth between the lines meaning while I have not forgotten

Tags: idioms

As you know about the idiom *read sth between the lines** it means:

> - To infer or understand the real or hidden meaning behind the superficial appearance of something. "Lines" refers to lines of text on a printed page etc.

The question is that whether there is such an idiom in English or not:

> - **Say** sth between the lines

Meaning: **"while I have not forgotten and in order to prevet from missing sth I feel I should mention it right now"**

Please have a look on my self made example:

I am describing my teacher's characteristics to someone who keen on knowing her, and say:

> "She's truely smart! Emotional and over-sensitive individual who loves nature and most of the time during the break-time she reads some poems for us! Oh, **between the lines** she is a poet herself.

Does the bold part above work within my scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a common or natural expression, indeed I don't recall encountering "between the lines" used in anything like that way. I would expect many native speakers not to understand the meaning you are giving this. I would probably use "by the way" in place of "between the lines" in your example, or to give more emphasis "in addition" or "besides reading poems" or perhaps "I should also mention that".

Comment: Yes, "by the way" as a metaphor is exactly what A-friend asks for in his question: "while I have not forgotten and in order to prevent from missing sth I feel I should mention it right now". "By the way," in other words, "while it is in sight our path, not to miss it later in the journey, let's point it out now."